# Call an anonymous function from another

Tags: php

I have an anonymous function that works when called directly. However, when I try to call it from another anonymous function, I get the error

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in ...(fileName)

Here is the complete code. Appreciate any thoughts on why this is failing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<?php
$ringW = 16; $ringCx = 8;
$ringH = 16; $ringCy = 8; $ringR = 7;
$penWidth = 2;

$svgCircle = function ($fillColor, $ringColor)
                use ($ringW, $ringH, $ringR, $ringCx, $ringCy, $penWidth) {
        echo "<svg width=\"$ringW\" height=\"$ringH\">";
        echo "<circle cx=\"$ringCx\" cy=\"$ringCy\" r=\"$ringR\" " .
        "stroke=\"$ringColor\" stroke-width=\"$penWidth\" fill=\"$fillColor\" />\n";
        echo "</svg>\n";
};


$pac = function ($condition) {
        if ($condition)
                // echo "Hello world\n";        // pass
                $svgCircle("yellow", "green");  // fails
};

?>

<head>
   <title>LVCC Algorithm</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
        $pac(1);
        $svgCircle("yellow", "green");  // pass
        $svgCircle("yellow", "green");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the function scope in `$pac`?

Comment: Should be the same as svgCircle - I did not specify anything otherwise. Not sure if I need to do something here, hence the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to make `$svgCircle` available to your second function

```
$pac = function ($condition) use ($svgCircle) {...};
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```